# SQL Server should I format with ReFS to get rid of operating system error 665?

Tags: sql-server-2016, windows-server, dbcc-checkdb

I have 13 production SQL Servers

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU11) (KB4527378) - 13.0.5598.27 (X64)   Nov 27 2019 18:09:22   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: )

Of them, one server has a vldb (1.5 tera). I've had the error 665 a few times over the last year.

> The operating system returned error 665(The requested operation could not be completed due to a file system limitation) to SQL Server during a write at offset...

I noticed the following patterns :

- I don't get this error for databases smaller than 1.5 terabytes and that are not used as much as this one.

But when the database gets to 1.5 terabytes, or when the client uses it a lot, I get error 665.

To correct the problem last time, I did the following:

- I splitted my database into different smaller filegroups
- I implemented the check table divided in 7 days as written in [Paul Randall's blog](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/checkdb-from-every-angle-consistency-checking-options-for-a-vldb/)
- I implemented a data maintenance for history data and was able to shrink down the database to around 1 terabyte in size
- I stop all non essential jobs while the CHECKTABLE runs and start them back again after.

I was able to get rid of the problem for a good 8 month. However, the database grew back and the problem returned yesterday.

This time, I'm considering reformatting the server with ReFS, as recommended [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/1450-and-665-errors-running-dbcc) by Microsoft.

I've read a lot of negative things with ReFS and I'm a little bit scared.

- Anyone ever tried it?
- Did you have problems?
- Anyone ever fixed error 665 permanently?

Thanks! I like to sleep at night.

Comment: Last I checked you had to disable integrity streams in order to get things like checkdb to work. Disabling that resulted in a measurable performance hit in my tests.

Comment: @swasheck Oh thank you for your answer!! I guess I won't be turning ReFS on then.